# Does pass by reference for Reference Type change the address on heap?

Tags: c#, .net, reference-type

I want to understand whether the memory address of an object changed when pass by reference to function as per Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference-an-example). While verifying I saw something different. Address for these objects remained the same as shown in the attached image. My understanding is that address for main object t1 should be changed as the new object is assigned.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test t1 = new Test() { a = 10 };
        GetCallByRefForObj(ref t1);
    }

    public static void GetCallByRefForObj(ref Test x)
    {
        x = new Test() { a = 10 };
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's a `ref` to a location which stores a reference to `Test`. So it's a reference of a reference. Therefore there is no reason for it to change when you reassign the `Test` reference being pointed to. That location is not stored on the heap, it's on the stack at `t1`.

Comment: You're watching the address *of* `t1`, not the address of the object referred to by `t1`

Comment: @Charlieface Microsoft link refers a similar example but claimed that  "If you change the value in the storage location of the parameter (to point to a new object), you also change the storage location to which the caller refers"

Comment: What they mean is that with `ref` you can make the original variable refer to a different object. That "changes the storage location to which the caller refers" if you interpret that as "the storage location accessed through the variable", not the storage location *of* the variable (which cannot really move in any reasonable way)

Comment: Got it. Here new object is sharing same memory location as oppose to call by value when new object assignment change the memory location.